# Who called Capitol citizens to the residence to form a human shield?

Tags: the-hunger-games, mockingjay

At the very end of *Mockingjay*, the Capitol citizens are called to the president's residence where they are promised food, shelter, and medicine. Children are encouraged to the very front.

This seems like this is the doing of President Snow — and it has the benefit of creating a human shield for him.

But it also nicely fits into the plans of President Coin — especially the final attack designed to break Katniss. Coin would have had to known that the citizens were coming to the president's residence to plan that final attack.

Did President Coin hack into the Capitol's communication system to broadcast the message attracting the citizens to the president's residence?

Comment: Are we talking about the book, or the movie? In the book, it’s the Head Peacekeeper who announces that Snow will be taking in refugees in his mansion, so there’s little doubt that it’s an official message.

Comment: We never get a definite answer but Snow denies it was him and Gale doesn't want to talk about it.

Comment: In the movie, we only hear an announcement over loudspeakers, which could have easily been hacked. If you write an answer, you should note the continuity.

Comment: @OceanKnight - I think you mean the bombing - I'm talking about the calling of refugee citizens to the mansion. Who did that?

Comment: @RoboKaren Sorry, i assumed it was the same person who announced both. Now that i think of it I believe Snow asked the people to come and Coin orders the attack. There would have been more controversy if she invited the people(just to kill them).

Comment: Capitol communications were already hacked before the assault. I don't think it was planned by Coin to move all the citizens. Otherwise pacekeeprs would stop them before to reach the residence. Traps were also deactivated all along the way to the residence. Coin just took advantage of the situation. Gale does not want to talk about because the final strike have his signature: a two phase strike.

Comment: @Laiv but why didnt snow open the gates right away>?

Comment: Snow is a tyrant. He doesn't care about citizens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Book canon

We see that a Head Peacekeeper himself orders this:

> On the television, we watch a terse Head Peacekeeper lay out specific rules regarding how many people per square foot each resident will be expected to take in. He reminds the citizens of the Capitol that temperatures will drop well below freezing tonight and warns them that their president expects them to be not only willing but enthusiastic hosts in this time of crisis. Then they show some very staged-looking shots of concerned citizens welcoming grateful refugees into their homes. The Head Peacekeeper says the president himself has ordered part of his mansion readied to receive citizens tomorrow. He adds that shopkeepers should also be prepared to lend their floor space if requested.
> <sub>*Mockingjay*, chapter 24</sub>

It would be a *little* hard to get a Head Peacekeeper to do this if he wasn't acting on real orders ;).

As for the movie, I don't see why they would change what happened here to be on the orders of a different person, but don't take my word for it.